# Ansible service discovery for ECS Cluster

Tags: ansible, amazon-ecs, service-discovery

How can I let `Ansible` to discover `EC2` Instances for a `ECS` Cluster by its name or tag?

I tried to google it, but wasn't able to get this info...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Ansible [EC2 Inventory Source](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_ec2_inventory.html#parameters) supports querying by tag. As long as your Cluster's instances have a specific tag that should work.